# WP8 application how to handle exception thrown from Webbrowser.InvokeScript on another thread?

Tags: multithreading, exception, windows-phone-8, try-catch

I am trying to incorporate AdMob ads in my WP8 application and have noticed that a percentage of ads (usually the text based ones but not always) are throwing the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll
```

I did a lot of digging and have found out that some of the admob interstitials are having issues when trying to use InvokeScript (stacktrace below).

```
Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(int hr)
Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(string scriptName, string[] args)
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(string scriptName, string[] args)
GoogleAds.DLL!A.c778af7b26605e0bb7fadf1547d7f5530.c379e3fb7ee502b62de5eee847f1352a2(string c1966769b4ad56530475a20642e40c06c)
```

Presumably this is because of some of the ads not not being well formed (just a guess) but I'd like to know if there is any way for me to catch when the exception is thrown (haven't had any luck so far).  The Admob calls are using beginInvoke so they are not on the same thread and because of this the typical pattern below does NOT cause the breakpoint to be hit.  I have made sure visual studio option for "break when exceptions cross AppDomain or native/managed boundries" is checked.

under App()

```
UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
```

Handler Method:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender,     ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can catch these exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution to this issue and it has let me have an exception handler that will be called even if on a different thread.

http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/